# DNN 9.10 hyperlink manager has no tracking option

Tags: hyperlink, tracking

I'm using dnn 9.10.06. The hyperlink manager no longer shows a track link option.  The editor is DNNConnect.DKE

Did they do away with tracking links done this way?  Or am I missing something?

None of the tabs have the option.

[image: link manager]